# What did I do wrong with the MCP3426 ADC? - non linear output

Tags: microcontroller, analog, adc, voltage-divider, non-linear

I'm running the MCP3426 on 3.3V supply on my PCB. I want to measure a battery voltage from around 12.5V down to 8V. Doesn't have to be precise, 0.1V accuracy is sufficient.

I calculated a voltage divider to make sure I don't overshoot the max. 3.3V until 15V input.
So i came to the following values:
R2 / R1 = 1000 / 3900 = 0.2564, Where R2 is the input to the ADC.

I am then calculating the voltage using this formula for the LSB value:

[image: LSB Value]

So the complete formula looks like this:
Voltage = LSB * ADC_Value * Voltage_Divider

The theoretical voltage divider value was way too low, so I corrected it to 0.37.
the problem is, on the lower end, i'm measuring much higher values than expected.

At 12.1V, I measure 12.12V

At 5V, I measure 6.01V

At 3.3V, I measure 3.97V

What could I be possibly doing wrong so I'm getting this non linearity?
I mean this can't be the tolerances of the ADC...

Comment: you are using incorrect formula for the divider ... a 3900 ohms and 1000 ohms produce a factor of 0.2041 ... the formula is 1000/4900

Comment: Thanks, but the problem still consists, now 12V only gives an output of 6.69V, 5V --> 3.31V, 3.3V --> 2.19V

Comment: As I understand, with this divider you are above VRef at 12 V input. The results for 5 V and 3.3 V are consistent.

Comment: What actual resistor values are you using?

Comment: Ah, I see, so I should do the calculation with the internal VRef as max, not Vcc? - makes sense now - my bad. I will try to adjust and report back. These are the actual values that I'm using, but the tolerances I don't know.

Comment: Now it works - I used 5.6k for R2 and 1k for R1 to bring the voltage down. Although the calculated factor was completely wrong for the used formula. With the formula 1000/6600 = 0.151515 the output value was around factor 3 too low. So i calculated it up to reach the correct voltage at 12V. The factor now is 0.416. But main thing for me is, it works ;). Thanks guys.